# Python multiprocessing weird outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

So I've been trying to optimize my program with multiprocessing so that it processes information quicker but I have gotten some pretty strange results.

The code is as follows:

```
from random import randint
import multiprocessing
import time

t = time.time()

def dice_calc(rolls):
    mutex.acquire()
    global wins
    global loss
    while rolls > 0:

        dice1 = randint(1, 6)
        dice2 = randint(1, 6)

        if dice1+dice2 == 11 or dice1+dice2 == 7 or dice1 == dice2:
            wins += 1

        else:
            loss += 1

        rolls -= 1
    mutex.release()


mutex = multiprocessing.Lock()
wins = 0
loss = 0
rolls = 1000000

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=dice_calc, args=(rolls/4,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=dice_calc, args=(rolls/4,))
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=dice_calc, args=(rolls/4,))
    p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=dice_calc, args=(rolls/4,))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()

    print(wins)
    print(loss)
    #percentage = (wins / (wins + loss)) * 100
    #print("Calculated percentage of a roll fulfilling requirements are:", round(percentage, 2), "%")


print(round((time.time()-t), 3))
```

The purpose is to basically find out what the chance of two dices either having a sum of 7, 11 or being the same is. I have tried this same code with the threading module and that works great (giving no real benefits in terms of performance but hey, it works)

What grinds my gears is the output from this version using multiprocessing:

```
0.012
0.012
0.011
0.012
0
0
0.764
```

The first 4 values that are printed are the ones that confuse me a lot. There shouldn't be anything making those outputs possible, these values also vary from run to run. I believe they originate from p1, p2, p3 and p4.

The two values after this should not be 0 ( these values indicates number of wins and loss which together should add up to rolls which was 1 000 000)

The last value is the only one that makes sense. It's basically just a timer to check how long the program ran for.

If anybody has any insight to how I can get this working I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are seeing those odd values is because of your statement:

```
print(round((time.time()-t), 3))
```

If you indent that line, it will only execute under the module named `__main__`.

The reason this happens is because when creating a `Process()`, Python executes that process under a new instance with a different module name. So when execution finishes for the function `dice_calcs` returns and continues execution down the script, eventually reaching that line.

As well, you won't get any correct values back from your wins and losses variables because those exist in different Processes. When each Process references that wins variable, it is referencing it's own copy of that variable, not the one that exists in `__main__`.

To get the actual values for those variables back from the other modules, you need to implement some way to communicate across your modules.

Using something like a `Queue` from the `queue` module you can do the following:
(Note: the code I added is surrounded by `#######`)

```
from random import randint
import multiprocessing
import time

t = time.time()

def dice_calc(rolls, q):
    mutex.acquire()
    global wins
    global loss
    while rolls > 0:

        dice1 = randint(1, 6)
        dice2 = randint(1, 6)

        if dice1+dice2 == 11 or dice1+dice2 == 7 or dice1 == dice2:
            wins += 1

        else:
            loss += 1

        rolls -= 1

    ########
    #return wins and losses to queue
    q.put((wins,loss))
    ########
    mutex.release()


mutex = multiprocessing.Lock()
wins = 0
loss = 0
rolls = 1000000

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ########
    #create a multiprocessing.Queue() instance that spans across Processes
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    ########

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=dice_calc, args=(rolls/4,q))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=dice_calc, args=(rolls/4, q))
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=dice_calc, args=(rolls/4, q))
    p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=dice_calc, args=(rolls/4, q))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()

    ########
    #Get wins and losses from the queue
    for _ in range(4):
        item = q.get(timeout=5000)
        wins = wins + item[0]
        loss = loss + item[1]
    ########    

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()
    p4.join()

    print(wins)
    print(loss)
    #percentage = (wins / (wins + loss)) * 100
    #print("Calculated percentage of a roll fulfilling requirements are:", round(percentage, 2), "%")

    ########
    #Added an indent to this line
    print(round((time.time()-t), 3))
    ########
```

Comment: Oh right, that was a pretty dumb mistake... I am however stuck with the wins and loss variables not changing their values. Do you know what may be the cause of this?

Comment: Have a look now!